# Change Localhost port effect mysql

Tags: mysql, iis

I had changed my localhost server port from 80 to other port due to some requirement but due this mysql has been also stopped.

How can i update mysql localhost communication.

Please let me know thank you.

Server have

IIS , MYSQL

Comment: I don't think changing the HTTP port should have any effect on MySQL. Mysql uses port 3306.

Comment: Why mysql is closed after some time

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xampp Control Panel, click to <kbd>Service and Port settings</kbd> and set `Main port` number as your port number is.